# QFileDialog with default directory

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4, cross-platform

How to create cross platform `QFileDialog` with default directory?

I have a code like

```
QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,"Save File","/home",tr("Any File (*.*);;Text file (*.txt);;Compressed file (*.zip *.tar *.rar);;Image (*.png *.xpm *.jpg *.tiff)"))
```

This works fine with Linux. But in windows the users directory will be `"C:\Users"`. I don't know in Mac. I need this dialogue with default directory as user folder. How to do that?

I saw the `toNativeSeparators()` but this need more line of codes. Is there any easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`QDir::home()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#home), and then [`QDir::cdUp()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#cdUp) to go up one.

Answer (score 4):

You can use also:

`QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::HomeLocation)`

Which returns the user's home directory.

Answer (score 4):

this is my code

```
QString pathExport = dialog->getExistingDirectory(this, "Pilih Folder Export",QDir::homePath(),QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly)+"/"+fileExport;
```